# How to call Sidekiq process on Rails application using kubernetes cluster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kubernetes, sidekiq, delayed-job

I run my Rails Application production on kubernetes cluster. One node for Rails process, 1 node for  Sidekiq for cronjob.
I call delay jobs on Rails Application, it can not run because the sidekiq process does not appear on Rails Node. What should I do please?
On Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

On docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -e production
```

Can I run multiple process on one cluster Or call to another node for Job?

Comment: You need another node for the `sidekiq` process, `sidekiq` is not a cron, this is a background job manager, so when the rails server will need to send an email or need to schedule a background job, it will push it into `redis` (default behavior) and then the `sidekiq` node will process it.

Comment: Since Sidekiq 7.0 it supports running in [embedded mode](https://www.mikeperham.com/2022/10/27/sidekiq-7.0-embedding/). Which means it runs embedded in the Rails application's Puma process. This is certainly not the best idea for applications with a lot of load and a huge number of background jobs. But for smaller apps, this can simplify the setup significantly.

Comment: Didn't know about it, that's interesting :+1: IMO not really suitable for production though, especially when using k8s, this is probably meaning that the app is going to handle a bunch of traffic and they want scalability.

Answer (score 0):

You have your entrypoint script hard-wired to only run the Rails server.  A better approach would be to separate this setup from the actual command to run.  If a Dockerfile has both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD` then [the `CMD` is passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), and you can combine this with the shell `exec "$@"` construct to replace the entrypoint script with the main container process.

In a Ruby context, you probably need to run most things under Bundler, and I'd fold that into the final line.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# docker-entrypoint.sh
...

exec bundle exec "$@"
```

In the Dockerfile, you'd both specify the `ENTRYPOINT` as you have it now, but also the default `CMD` to run.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -e production
```

Now, the benefit of doing this is that you can replace the `CMD` when you run the container.  In plain Docker, you'd pass the command after the `docker run image-name`

```bash
docker run ... image-name sidekiq
```

The entrypoint wrapper would still run, and clean up the Rails pid file, and run `sidekiq` under Bundler instead of running the Rails server.

Bringing this up to Kubernetes, you would have two separate Deployments, one for the Rails server and one for the Sidekiq worker.  Somewhat confusingly, Kubernetes uses different names for the two parts of the command; `command:` overrides Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`, and `args:` overrides `CMD`.  So for this setup you need to specify `sidekiq` as the `args:`, and leave the `command:` alone.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: image-name
---
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: worker
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: worker
          image: image-name
          args:
            - sidekiq
```

Only the main application needs a matching Service (if you're using the Istio service mesh, it has different requirements) and you need to make sure the `spec: { template: { metadata: { labels: } } }` can disambiguate the two sets of Pods.  Either or both parts can independently have non-default `replicas:` and a matching HorizontalPodAutoscaler.